# How do I extract data from multiple worksheets into a dynamic list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to extract data from several worksheets and sort them according to date in a dynamic list that changes automatically when the worksheets are edited/expanded. I would like to use a formula for this. Preferably the new list should also disregard blank rows.

Example (I'm using UK date format):

```
Worksheet A                     Worksheet B
----------                      ----------
Column A      Column B          Column A      Column B                    
11/01/2019    Apples            12/01/2019    Lemons
14/01/2019    Pears             14/01/2019    Grapefruits
23/02/2019    Plums             22/02/2019    Oranges
...                             ...
```

Sort into:

```
Worksheet C
----------
Column A     Column B
11/01/2019   Apples
12/01/2019   Lemons
14/01/2019   Grapefruits
14/01/2019   Pears
22/02/2019   Oranges
23/02/2019   Plums
...
```

I have been playing around with [sub-arrays](https://www.exceltactics.com/make-filtered-list-sub-arrays-excel-using-small/5/) and such but can't get to the bottom of the solution for my particular problem. I don't want to use VBA nor any built in Excel sort features.

I hope this is not too overkill for a formula.
Thanks.

Comment: `I hope this is not too overkill for a formula.` that depends on how much data there is.  The formulas would need to be array type formula, they would be long and unwieldy.  Modifying them later would be a task and difficult to manage.  VBA really is the correct method here.  Why the aversion?

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for [**Power Query**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-microsoft-power-query-for-excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605) and [Union](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/combine-multiple-queries-power-query-16b1421c-9708-466a-8d6e-30a324949722)

Comment: @ScottCraner I guess I don't want to learn another programming language just to make this work. I also would like the document to be universal enough for other programs.

Comment: to me learning how to copy/paste/sort in a Worksheet_Change event would be easier than learning the intricacies and volatility of long array formula code.

Comment: @ScottCraner For my particular issue, it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @chrisneilsen this task can be handled by `#powerquery`.

Please refer to this [article](https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/) to find out how to use **Power Query** on your version of Excel. It is availeble in **Excel 2010 Professional Plus and later versions**.

The steps are:

1. Add both tables from your worksheet A and B to the power query editor;
2. Use **Append Queries** function under the `Home` tab to combine the two table (into a new one by choice);
3. Sort Column A ascending;
4. **Close & Load** the combined table into a new worksheet (by default).

Each time you make changes to the source tables on Worksheet A and/or B, you just need to go to the combined table, right click somewhere within the table and select **Refresh** to update the output (and there are other ways to refresh data that you can google the know how).

Let me know if you have encountered any problem.

Cheers :)